# Access variable in ionViewDidLoad (Ionic 3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem accessing a variable created in `ionViewDidLoad` in a ts within my app.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { CarreerDataProvider } from '../../providers/carreer-data/carreer-data';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    clientName = "hola";
    carrera={
        kind: 'key'
    }
    modeKeys = [
        {'key':"pablo","precio":"500","precio2":"500"},
        {'key':"juan","precio":"500","precio2":"500"},
        {'key':"lili","precio":"500","precio2":"500"},
        {'key':"juan","precio":"500","precio2":"500"},
        {'key':"juan","precio":"500","precio2":"500"},
    ]

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public carreerService: CarreerDataProvider, public http: Http) {
        console.log("constructorLoading");
    }

    ionViewDidLoad(){  
        var jlink = 'http://nimbler.app-senescyt.sachiel.xyz/universidad-rest';
        var getItem = function(ids) {
            console.log('hola');
            console.log(ids);
            return ids;
        };
        //Auto Json
        var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("get", url, true);
            xhr.responseType = "json";
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                if (status == 200) {
                    callback(null, xhr.response);
                }
                else {
                    callback(status);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        };
        //start Json
        getJSON(jlink, function(err, data) {
            if (err != null) {
                console.log('No wiki data code found');
            }
            else {
                var i =0;
                var total = Object.keys(data).length;
                var ids = [];
                for(i; i < total; i++) {
                    if (ids.indexOf(data[i].field_provincia) == -1) {
                        ids.push(data[i].field_provincia);
                    }
                }
                // Start axctionable code.
                getItem(ids);
                // End actionable code.
            }
        });
    }

    ionViewDidEnter(){
        console.log("IonViewEnter");
    }
}
```

The variables `carrera` and `modeKeys` are used to localy populate an `ion-select` in the HTML.
What I want to do is use the array `ids` created in `ionViewDidLoad` from a webservice to populate this `ion-select` as I do with `modeKeys`. I've tried many methods with no success.

Hope you can help me with my issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http.get(fileonOSsystem) and load your json files directly off drive for mocking screen layouts. See [here](http://4dev.tech/2016/09/how-to-load-a-json-file-in-angular2/). Exact same principle in Angular and Ionic. Example creates folder /data off project root. Same applies to Ionic.
`ionic g provider Data` - will create a service call DataService for you in the /providers folder and should wire it into app-modules.. and create @Injectable service for you.. Write the http.get in that..

Comment: Mind detailing more? I'm a newbie in Ionic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this `XMLHttpRequest`, you should use `Http` from `@angular/http`. To use it properly, you can create a provider like this:

Create a provider (named request for example) with `ionic g provider request`

Insert the provider into `app.module.ts`, to make it available in your app (you can do this, by importing it and then listing it in providers).

```
import { RequestService } from '../providers/request-service.ts';
 ...

 @NgModule({
   providers: [
     RequestService
   ]
 })
```

Now you can start working with the provider. The most important things are already imported by default. Start writing a function called `get` for example.

```
public get (url: string) : any {
  this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}
```

Finally you can return back to your page and use the provider by importing it.

```
import { RequestService } from '../providers/request-service.ts';
 ...    

private data: any;
 ...

  constructor(public request: RequestService) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.data = this.request.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }
```

**Note** that there is no error handling at the moment. So the variable `data` will probably stay undefined, when request fails.